# Unresolved reference when using openApiGenerate build.gradle.kts

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, openapi-generator

I'm trying to get openapigenerator to help get responses automatically from a swagger for my mocked api. the build.gradle.kts looks like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven("http://repo1.maven.org/maven2")
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.openapitools:openapi-generator-gradle-plugin:6.3.0")
    }
}

plugins {
    id("org.openapi.generator") version "6.3.0"
}

apply(plugin = "org.openapi.generator")

openApiGenerate {
        generatorName = "java"
        inputSpec = "$rootDir/path/to/openapi.yaml".toString()
        outputDir = "$buildDir/generated".toString()
    }
```

I reload my gradle and can see it downloading openapi but it keeps saying "Unresolved reference" for openApiGenerate and all the variables inside.I'm new to kotlin and gradle any help would be appreciated

Comment: I haven't used this plugin so I can't speak to that syntax, but you seem to be trying to load your plugin two different ways, which maybe causes a conflict? Remove that `dependencies` block and the `apply` line.

Comment: this possibly could of been the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`openApiGenerate` is a task therefore you must use `tasks` to configure it. You appear to be mixing Groovy syntax with Kotlin, review [Gradle Kotlin DSL Primer](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html).

Additionally, you are mixing the [plugins DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block) and [legacy plugin application](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:old_plugin_application). The plugins DSL is the preferred way to apply plugins.

```
plugins {
    id("org.openapi.generator") version "6.3.0"
}

tasks.openApiGenerate {
    generatorName.set("java")
    // and so on, let your IDE assist you.
}
```